# Why is the Degrees of Freedom 1 higher when model run with Poisson than Negative Binomial

Tags: poisson-distribution, model, negative-binomial-distribution, degrees-of-freedom, glmmtmb

Because the Negative Binomial distribution would result in there be an extra parameter to estimate the over dispersion, I am confused as to why I am getting a DF of 94 when I run the model with Poisson and a DF of 93 when I run the model with Negative Binomial.

Here's the model:

```
mod1 <- glmmTMB(sum.50 ~ trtmt_simple + julian2 + min_aft_sunrise2 + mintemp2 +
                 (1|site), data = bcch_combo, ziformula=~1, family=poisson)
```

Here's the part of the summary output where DF = 94:

````
Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula:          sum.50 ~ trtmt_simple + julian2 + min_aft_sunrise2 + mintemp2 + 
                    (1 | site)
Zero inflation:          ~1
Data: bcch_combo

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   419.3    440.3   -201.6    403.3       94 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 site   (Intercept) 6.969e-10 2.64e-05
Number of obs: 102, groups:  site, 9
```
````

Comment: I don't follow.  You open your question with its own answer: the degrees of freedom are reduced by one for each additional parameter.  Could you clarify where you need help?

Comment: Note that the output is showing the *residual* degrees of freedom, not the degrees of freedom of the model.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thank you for pointing that out, you are right.

Comment: @whuber, that is what I didn't realize. So simple, but I missed that. Thank you.